# Addthis "Application Error" on a phonegap android app

Tags: cordova, addthis

I get this error (image attached) anytime I include the addthis script in my project:

http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js

I have whitelisted all addthis domains and sub-domains, any ideas?

Thanks![image]

Comment: Looks like your app is trying to retrieve the file locally (file://ct1.addthis.com/static...) - not sure how you would do this, but you need to make sure it's using "http" as the protocol to retrieve the file.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you connect to the internet on the device? Have you added the INTERNET permission?

Answer (score 0):

***Note*** this doesn't really work, as it won't bring the content you want to share along to the webpage of all the social sites, so maybe I should retract this answer

===

I had this error too, but only on Android 4.1 (Samsung Galaxy SII), but not on an Android 2.3 device.

I found a work around, which does work for both Android versions I have here, but untested on iOS. I downloaded the `addthis_widget.js` and looked through the file, the host names are just `"//ct1.addthis.com"` etc (there are about 6 or 7 urls in there). So I edited the file add appended `"http:"` to start of theses hostnames, and referenced my local copy of `addthis_widget.js`.  You should probably do one at a time to make sure it doesn't break other things until it works for you.  Tested it on the 4.1 and 2.3 android and it doesn't crash, and the addthis sharing page comes up.

Note I don't know enough javascript to know what is the root cause of the problem within their js file, but this work around works for me.